# Converting database to facts in Prolog

Tags: prolog

So I have database which looks something like:

```
DB = [
    data([table, keyboard,cup, box,watch]),
    data([green,red, yellow,white,blue]),
    data([alex, john,sasha,  sabrina,  ben]),
    data([coffee, tea,  syrup,  vodka, beer]),
    data([bookA, bookB, bookC, bookD, bookE])
]
```

I would like to save `DB` as a fact. Then we should create a relation `db_to_facts` which finds all the facts.

Example:

```
data([true, false]).
data([dog,cat]).
```

Output:

```
db_to_facts(DB).
DB = [data([true, false]), data([dog, cat])].
```

What would be the cleanest way possible to achieve it?

Edit:

I think I got it:

```
db_to_facts(L) :- findall(data(X),data(X),L).
```

But if the database is empty, it will fail. How to make it return empty list?

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning of your Prolog program, use the directive, `dynamic(data/1).`. This tells Prolog you have a dynamic database that can change over time and will still recognize the `data(X)` query even if there is no data.

Without the directive:

```
1 ?- data(X).
ERROR: Undefined procedure: data/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)
2 ?-
```

With the directive:

```
2 ?- dynamic(data/1).
true.

3 ?- data(X).
false.
```

And then your `findall/3` call will yield `[]` if there is no data.

Answer (score 0):

For sure, the usage of `dynamic(data/1)` is the best way. Just to let you know, there is another way to check if `data/1` exists. You can use `current_predicate/2` in this way:

```
db_to_facts(L):-
    ( current_predicate(data,_) -> findall(data(X),data(X),L) ; L = []).
```

If you compile it (you cannot use swish online, it gives `No permission to call sandboxed ...`) you get a warning saying that you should define `data/1` but if you run the query anyway you get the empty list:

```
?- db_to_facts(L).
L = [].
```

It's not the cleanest way but it works :)